# Check that std::make_unique is supported via CMake target_compile_feature

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to ensure that `std::make_unique` is supported via CMake `target_compile_feature`?

Something like:

```
target_compile_feature (target_name
    cxx_make_unique # won't work.
)
```

Comment: Check for C++14 or better. That should be enough.

Comment: `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`